# Assigning props to variable in React class component

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react component. I would like to assign a variable inside the component method to `props`. I've tried this method works with functional components:

```
class Pets extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

 const {dog, cat, frog} = props
 // the code on the line above does not work

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {dog.name}
       {cat.name}
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: does it throw an error or does it just not assign? are you passing in the props to the component?

Comment: What were you expecting? It's just bad class declaration - _'Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.'_ error appears in stackblitz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That will not work. `props` is a property on the instance of the component you created with `<Pets />` JSX for example. It needs to be inside the instance methods of the class `Pets`. It will work if you do it in the `render` method by `const {dog, cat, frog} = this.props`. `props` in the class body as you have now in the question is not what them expected to be.

Inside the `constructor` function just `const {dog, cat, frog} = props` will work, because here `props` object is received as an argument. so `this.props` (after the `super(props)` line)`and`props` is same object.

Generally you unpack props where you need them, for example you need those inside the `render` to create some output, so you *unpacked* it there. I tried to explain in this answer what `props` means in the class body, and instance methods body, how you can access the `props` in different methods etc. But as [xadm said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335399/assigning-props-to-variable-in-react-class-component/52335484?noredirect=1#comment91621543_52335484), unpacking them inside the constructor by thinking you will access them later in other methods will not work due to the scope boundary, unless you store them as a property to the instance again using `this.dog = props.dog`. But this is an horrible idea, never do this. Just unpack them when you need any property from props object in that place only.

Comment: in constructor it will work but vars declared(f.e. `dog` ) won't be accessible in render because of scope.

Comment: @xadm yes,, I said it needs `this.props`.

Comment: I mean - const declared this way in constructor (OP intendet to be class scope declaration?) won't be available in render.

Comment: sorry, @xadm, what do you mean it won't be available in the render? the solution works for me

Comment: `const {dog, cat, frog} = props` in constructor gives `dog` valid only in `constructor` scope. Refering to `dog` in `render` (`dog.name`) won't give you access the same const (`dog` declared in constructor). You have to use another `const {dog, cat, frog} = this.props`. Of course both are derived from the same props object but I've read this code in an intention to be object scope declaration like `const this.dog = props.dog` from `constructor` will be accessible as `this.dog` (`this.dog.name`) in `render`.

Comment: Unapcking when needed, ok ... it's a common practice ... _'never do this'_ ... there are some (edge) cases when using it ( `this.sth`) can be suitable - saving prop (w/o using setState), update or compare props changed in different lifecycles... when you want to save it but don't always want to re-render.

Comment: Well when something already is available via the props, why do I store it again on component instance? @xadm

Comment: I wrote - edge cases - f.e. prop can change and you're lost when need to compare with earlier values (many of them or simply only initial with many updates) not only with the last one (which can be done in `componentDidUpdate()`).

Comment: Just remember about this possibility (you don't have to use `setState` to save values) and use it when needed :)